# What is this gtk widget called

Tags: user-interface, gtk, gtk3, gnome, gtkmm

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfeuL.png)

I'm talking about the circled part and to give further context you can drag it then it becomes a standalone window looking thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're the tabs of a [`GtkNotebook`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.Notebook.html).

For future reference, if you want a visual overview of the widgets in GTK: the documentation provides a [widget gallery](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/visual_index.html#containers)

Comment: yes, I actually figured it out about an hour after I posted this. However, the widget gallery will be very helpful yes so thanks a lot for sharing it xd.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem ;)